# VB.NET MultiThreading Unlimited Threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm having a small issue with my program as it shows below, I want to use more than 1 thread but I have to dim each one and address each one to the specific sub, I've done this before but I haven't used VB.Net in a long time and I forgot how, any possible help? Thanks to anyone who reads/helps with this.

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

Dim thread As System.Threading.Thread
Dim ct as boolean = True

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Main)
    thread.Start()
End Sub

Sub Main()
    Do Until ct = False
        'Executes something
    Loop
End Sub

End Class
```

Here's an example

```
Dim x As Integer = 1
Private Sub asd()
    Do Until x = 50
        Dim thread & x As System.Threading.Thread
        thread & x = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Main)
        thread & x.Start()
        x = x + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

The above is an example that I want 50 thread, this doesn't work its just the idea.

Comment: Google for Task Parallel Library and Task.Run

Comment: There's rarely a need to specifically create a new thread yourself in .NET these days - there's usually a better approach.  But the best approach depends entirely on what you're trying to achieve, and what this `'Executes something` is actually doing.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've checked that and wasn't able to get something that actually runs I was hoping I can get some explanation here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a bad idea; that many threads does not necessarily equal better performance.

...but this is how your code would need to look:

```
Private Threads As New List(Of Thread)

Private Sub asd()
    For i As Integer = 1 To 50
        Dim t As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Main)
        Threads.Add(t)
        t.Start()
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @Trevor you both gave working answers and this is awesome! But I have a small question, my intention of this amount of threads is to speed up the processing I'm doing, why is it that more than 10 threads it gets slow? This uses network and I have 40MBps I suppose that's enough? With a i7-6700k
Also a question aside, is it better to put all the process I'm doing into 1 sub or split since I'm using more than 1 thread? Only 1 sub, correct?

Comment: @slammyslam23 More threads doesn't mean more performance, especially if performance is not CPU bounded.  Again, as per my original comment, what is it you're actually doing?  Having more threads than you've got actual cores in your CPU doesn't make sense, and even less so if it's not a bottleneck on the CPU in the first place.

Comment: @JamesThorpe 1 button to execute a sub that is the answer above ^ which assigns threads to use a sub that generates a link, goes onto the link, checks for specific strings, if true then saves link into a notepad, if not then re-uses the sub (basically searching for something)

Comment: @slammyslam23, there is a TON of overhead switching tasks and as James mentioned, unless you have a 50 core CPU you end up losing performance. If Is better to sue a single thread that sequences through the 50 operations.

Comment: Each "Operation" could be multi step... The sequencing code knowing what to do with each operation depending on some step counter variable. But we are going way deeper that is answerable in comments.

Comment: @Trevor I just ended up using 8 threads and keeping everything in one sub for the sake of no strings get mistaken between each thread's work, I really appreciate your replies and I've finally got it to work, 8 threads for my processor are decent enough because of which CPU I have, thank you very much for the answers and useful information, will be sure to keep it in mind! I've took everything you said into consideration!

Comment: Good man, muti-threading is a bit of an art. The water is a LOT deeper than most realize when they start using them.

Comment: You may want to post your thread code in the code review page though if it is not secret. Someone may be able to tune it up a bit for you. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vb.net

Answer (score 0):

I'd just add them to a `List` object:

```
Dim Threads As New List(Of System.Threading.Thread)

Private Sub asd()
    For X As Integer = 0 To 49
        Threads.Add(New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Main))
        Threads(x).Start
    Next
End Sub
```

> Note `Threads` uses zero start index.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim Threads As New List(Of System.Threading.Thread)

Private Sub asd()
  For X As Integer = 0 To 49
      Threads.Add(New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Main))
      Threads(x).Start
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @MhdAlaaAlhaj I feel like you copy pasted my wording :)